Using Netflix in flutter WebView
I was trying to replicate the Rave App App by making its clone in flutter.
I was able to play YouTube videos by using webview package and it is able to replicate the same functionality as in original app. But I am facing issue in palying videos from netflix. I was able to to navigate and login to the netflix by using the webview but whenever I click to a video it show me an error.
please help me to solve this issue in webview or just tell me How these genius people are able run netflix & prime content in their app??
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NetFlix extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<NetFlix> createState() => _NetFlixState();
}

class _NetFlixState extends State<NetFlix> {



 WebViewController controller = WebViewController();



 @override
  void initState() {
 controller
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(https://netflix.com/login/));
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   return
Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 10, 10),
                  leading: IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'NETFLIX',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                  centerTitle: true,
                ),
                body: WebViewWidget(
                  controller: controller,
                ),
              )
 ;

  }
}

